# Change default monitor for Windows 8 Metro?

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8, modern-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 8 start screen on secondary monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/480506/windows-8-start-screen-on-secondary-monitor)

To clarify, this is NOT for traditional default monitor. Let me explain my scenario:

I have a 3 monitor setup, I would like to maintain the primary (default) monitor in the middle, however,  this also makes the metro start menu default to the middle. I would like to change the default Metro start menu to the right monitor.

I know that I can change this temporarily by opening up any metro app and dragging it to the right, this setting will not change for future boots.

I'm hoping there is a simple registry fix for this. Has anyone tried this yet?

UPDATE:

Temporary fixes include:

1. Moving the mouse in the bottom left corner and opening the start menu will keep the Start menu on a secondary monitor, as long as it is not repeated on another monitor, or the computer does not reboot.
2. Use keyboard commands  Win-PageUp/Win-PageDown to move the start menu between monitors. Again, this is a temporary measure and will not stay through a reboot.

Is a permanent fix possible? I will poke through the registry tonight and see if I can find anything.

Comment: Put your mouse on the bottom left corner of any monitor and click start screen image to show the Metro UI. Then the next time you press start button, metro will show up on that screen just as if you've dragged it there.

Comment: Why are people so quick to mark Win 8 questions as dup these days? The op is asking for a way to peg the metro UI to one screem which is not addressed in the other question.

Comment: @billc.cn: Unless i'm mistaken it does "When you open the start screen, press Win-PageUp or Win-PageDown to switch it to the next monitor. It will continue to open on the other monitor until you switch it back."

Comment: @billc.cn, Yes, putting the mouse in the bottom left corner will temporarily keep the metro start screen on a secondary monitor, and George Duckett, the Win-PageUp/PageDown option is a bit faster, however both methods are not permanent. A reboot brings the start menu back to the Primary Monitor, but thank you both for your quick responses!