# Set display number for Windows 8 Start Menu

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 8 start screen on secondary monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/480506/windows-8-start-screen-on-secondary-monitor)

I have Windows 8 Professional x64 running on a custom build desktop with an AMD Radeon HD5850, with the most up-to-date display driver. I've set my middle display to be the "main display" in Windows, however the Start Menu (modern UI) still shows up on the left-hand display.

How do I change the display that the Modern UI renders on?

Answer (score 1):

Move your mouse to the lower left hand corner of the desired display, until you see a tiny version of the start menu. Then press the Windows key. The start menu will now open on that display.

You can also start an app, and just drag it from the middle/top of the window onto the desired display.

The one thing I can't do so far is open the start menu on a different monitor from that of a running app.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the taskbar and disable 'lock taskbar'. Then drag it over to the other monitor, starting to drag somewhere between the application-buttons and the notification area.

Comment: That's the taskbar - which awesomely can now cover all displays, and you can toggle them to show all running desktop programs or just the ones on that display, vs. the Modern UI start menu.

Comment: Sound just like what I created http://yoy.be/sideswitch for, been using it since WinXP