# How can I set the default start screen of the windows 8 metro home screen?

Tags: windows-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows 8 start screen on secondary monitor](https://superuser.com/questions/480506/windows-8-start-screen-on-secondary-monitor)

I have a multi monitor setup with my laptop powering 3 monitors(2 external, 1 laptop monitor).

I have one of my external monitors set as my main display, but when I open the metro home screen it opens on my laptop monitor.

Is it possible to make this metro screen open on my main monitor ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Page Up</kbd> to move the Start Screen to a different monitor.