# Extend the Windows 8.1 screen on another monitor while in logon screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-8.1, hdmi, tv

to make things a little clear:

I connected my TV through a HDMI-cord with my computer.
My TV is in another room.
My Computers power adapter is connected with a remotely controlled Power Control. If i push a button on a remote from another room, power goes on and off for my PC.
"Power on LAN" is enabled on my PC. Means, as soon i press "ON" on that remote i just mentioned, PC boots up.
I got a bluetooth keyboard+mouse, to control my PC when i'm in the TV-Room.

Problem:

When i boot up my PC, using that remote from the TV-Room, i just have a black screen since i haven't extend the desktop prior on the PC. Even when i do this, the logon-screen still remans on the primary-monitor, which means i have to type in my password blindly.
I don't want to set the TV-Screen as primary screen manually and back all the time, either.
When i boot up the PC in the TV-Room, i want to stay in the TV-Room.

What i want:

A way to extend the display AND the logon-screen of Windows 8.1 to my TV-Screen, using only my bluethooth-keyboard + -mouse, all while beeing in the logon-screen.

Is There a way to do this?

Best Wishes

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I display the Windows 8 Start Screen on a secondary monitor?](http://superuser.com/questions/480506/how-can-i-display-the-windows-8-start-screen-on-a-secondary-monitor)

Answer (score 0):

It appears, the issue isn't that you haven't extended, more that you're focusing on the wrong screen (assuming I've understood).

You could change which screen the login screen starts on with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd>+<kbd>left arrow</kbd> or <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>[image: Windows Key]</kbd> +<kbd>right arrow</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same setup: PC in a room and TV in another room.

You can bring the logon screen to the TV by **BLINDLY** entering the following key sequence:

- Enter (go from lock screen to logon screen)
- Win + P (show project options)
- End (select second screen)
- Enter (confirm)

To bring the logon screen back to the PC:

- Enter
- Win + P
- Home
- Enter

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> will do the work for you if you are on Windows 8/Windows 8.1.
Select extend from options